# Setting up Charles proxy causes emulator to lose internet connection

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, charles-proxy

So I'm trying to set up Charles on a Mac (running Mavericks). I have Charles installed, set up the Proxy Settings by adding * as the SSL locations (which means it should accept traffic from everywhere, right?).

Then I went into my emulated Android device running 4.4.2 and went to  http://charlesproxy.com/charles.crt to get a certificate, accepted the certificate and added a pin to the emulated device for it, and it said it was installed.

The internet still works on the emulated device. I then go into my internet settings on this emulated device to set up the proxy to my machine, and after doing that, the internet dies out, and I cannot access anything. The only way to regain internet is to wipe the emulated device and start over. I've now done this a couple times to confirm the result and it is when I set my proxy settings on the device that the internet dies.

Anyone have any experience with this issue and could offer some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. My proxy settings that I was told were correct on the emulated device were actually incorrect, I was trying to use a device name instead of a local IP address. Make sure you use your local IP address, which can be found by (in Charles) going to Help->Local IP Address...